# Signed adder implementation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, integer-arithmetic, register-transfer-level

Suppose that I have two logic vectors:

```
logic [4:0] a;
logic [4:0] b;
```

that hold 2's complement values. I want to perform a subtraction and extend the result by 1 bit. For example, assume that I want to compute `-12 - 13` and store the result of `-25`:

```
logic [5:0] sum;
sum = a - b;
```

The above simulates as I expect and I get the expected value of `6'b100111`. Working through this by hand:

```
  1 0 1 0 0   -12
  1 0 0 1 0   invert bits of +13
          1   carry-in
---------------
1 0 0 1 1 1   = -25
```

So, the MSB of the result is simply the carry-out of the addition. However, if I compute `12 - 13`, the result should be `6'b111111`, but instead I get the simulated result of `6'b011111`. Working through this example by hand:

```
  0 1 1 0 0   12
  1 0 0 1 0   invert bits of +13
          1   carry-in
---------------
0 1 1 1 1 1   = +31
```

So, the result is not correct as the carry-out into the MSB is zero.

I can fix the simulated result by changing the RTL as follows:

```
logic [5:0] sum;
sum = $signed(a) - $signed(b);
```

which returns the expected result of `6'b111111`. After reading through the SystemVerilog LRM to understand what's happening here, I discovered that additions are done at the bit size of the largest operand, including the LHS of assignment operations. In addition, using the `$signed` keyword causes the 5-bit input operands to be sign-extended to 6-bits. Taking this into account and performing the operation by hand again:

```
[0] 0 1 1 0 0   12
[1] 1 0 0 1 0   invert bits of +13
            1   carry-in
---------------
 1  1 1 1 1 1   = -1
```

where `[0]` and `[1]` are the sign-extension bits. From this it is clear that the MSB is actually calculated by a full-adder (`[0] + [1] + carry-out from previous column`).

My question is this:

1. Am I correct in thinking that a signed adder does indeed require a full-adder on the MSB to calculate the correct result?
2. If above is correct, what will a synthesis tool make of this? Will it also know to instantiate a full-adder on the MSB?

I had always assumed that writing an adder in SystemVerilog, where the inputs are n-bits wide, would cause a synthesis tool to instantiate a n-bit adder where the (n+1)-bit output was simply the carry-out of that adder.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about sign extension. -13 (10011) in 6-bit incarnation is supposed to be 110011. Therefore, you are interpreting the second resulst incorrectly. It is not +31 (6-bit), it should be interpreted as `-1` in the 5-bit version. To make a 6-bit result do sigh-extend both operands:

```
  ext
  0 | 0 1 1 0 0   -- 12
  1 | 1 0 0 1 1   -- -13
  ==|==========
  1 | 1 1 1 1 1   -- -1 (6 bit)
```

With unsigned numbers only you can get away without extension, because it is always '0'.

Comment: Hi Serge, thanks for the answer. I do agree that sign-extension is required to get the correct result, I eventually figured that out. However,  I'm still not sure if a synthesis tool would interpret this correctly? It appears that to implement this circuit, it requires 1 additional full adder on the MSB, when compared to an adder that works on unsigned numbers. Is this the correct way of coding a signed adder (using $signed) or should I explicitly code it myself with the additional full adder on the MSB?

Comment: no , they will not. You need to design your model in such a way that the sign extension is built into it. So, at mininmum you would need 6 bit operands for a 6-bit answer.

Comment: So then what's the correct way of coding this? From what you're saying, this is enough? `sum = {a[4], a[4:0} - {b[4], b[4:0]}`. Is this different from `sum = $signed(a) - $signed(b)` ?

Comment: something like that would do

Comment: Don't use ```sum = {a[4], a[4:0} - {b[4], b[4:0]}```. Use ```sum = $signed(a) - $signed(b)```.

Comment: `$signed` is synthesizable by DC, but you need to check other synthesis tools if it is available there.